# Sort tabs based on values using php

Tags: php, sorting

I have 3 variables holding 3 different values(managed from admin).

```
$tab_download_pos = 2;
$tab_download_title = "Download";
$tab_overview_pos = 1;
$tab_overview_title = "Overview";
$tab_faq_pos = 3;
$tab_faq_title = "FAQ";
```

Now I have 3 tabs and I would like to sort the tabs based on the values from above variables.

The three tabs are

```
1.Overview
2.Download
3.Faq
```

I started in this way

```
$tab_arr = sort(array($tab_download_pos,$tab_overview_pos,$tab_faq_pos));
```

I did foreach loop but then I am lost. 
I would like to sort the tabs based on the values from the variables which I am getting from backend.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the positions guaranteed to be 1, 2 and 3? Or can they for example be 1, 2 and 4, with none having 3?

Comment: @trincot Good question. Yes they can be 1,2,4. The admin may or may not add tab 3 from admin.

Comment: OK, I have posted my answer to cope with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to sort. Just need to put them in an array, sort it by key with [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), and iterate over them:

```
$a = array();
$a[$tab_download_pos] = $tab_download_title;
$a[$tab_overview_pos] = $tab_overview_title;
$a[$tab_faq_pos] = $tab_faq_title;
ksort($a);
foreach($a as $p => $title) {
  echo "$p.$title\n";
}
```

Comment: It works great if the sequence is 1,2,3 but if it is 1,3,4 then it breaks. Do I need to use a function like maximum key of array $a and then remove 4 from for loop and use that max value. Thanks.

Comment: @Raj, I see. ksort can already order an array by key. see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the numbers might not be without gaps, I would suggest to create one data structure containing both titles and positions, and then sort it on position:

```
$tab_download_pos = 2;
$tab_download_title = "Download";
$tab_overview_pos = 1;
$tab_overview_title = "Overview";
$tab_faq_pos = 4;
$tab_faq_title = "FAQ";

$tab_arr = array(
    array( "pos" => $tab_download_pos, "title" => $tab_download_title ),
    array( "pos" => $tab_overview_pos, "title" => $tab_overview_title ),
    array( "pos" => $tab_faq_pos,      "title" => $tab_faq_title ),
);

usort($tab_arr, function ($a, $b) { return $a["pos"] - $b["pos"]; });
```

The array then looks like this:

```
array (
  array (
    'pos' => 1,
    'title' => 'Overview',
  ),
  array (
    'pos' => 2,
    'title' => 'Download',
  ),
  array (
    'pos' => 4,
    'title' => 'FAQ',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's working exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code. Do not save sort into variable it only gives you Boolean value. Do it in this way

```
<?php

$tab_download_pos = 2;
$tab_download_title = "Download";
$tab_overview_pos = 1;
$tab_overview_title = "Overview";
$tab_faq_pos = 3;
$tab_faq_title = "FAQ";

$tab_arr = [$tab_download_pos,$tab_overview_pos,$tab_faq_pos];

sort($tab_arr);

print_r($tab_arr);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```